# ZK menuitem image not showing

Tags: java, html, user-interface, zk, zul

i have this code

```
<image src='/img/navigation/delete.png'/> the image shows OK.
<menupopup id="listmenu">
   <menuitem label="Delete" image="img/navigation/delete.png"/>//image dont show at all
</menupopup>
```

i have also try using single quotes double quotes without success starting with slash or without also try static internet resources.

```
image='/img/navigation/delete.png'
image='img/navigation/delete.png'
image="/img/navigation/delete.png" 
image="img/navigation/delete.png"       
image="https://www.google.com.tw/images/icons/product/chrome-128.png"
```

the image on the image tag shows good but dont show on the menuitem even when they have the same path...

**UPDATE**

i have check the sample provided by ZK and this is the ZUL code [Zk Official Page](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/menu/context_menu)

```
<menuitem image="/widgets/menu/context_menu/img/UserProfileMale-16x16.png" label="Profile" />
```

this generate this HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="b9FVk-a" class="z-menuitem-content">
   <img src="/zkdemo/widgets/menu/context_menu/img/UserProfileMale-16x16.png;jsessionid=690619C76D278163402749B336894F89.zkdemo" class="z-menuitem-image" align="absmiddle"> 
   <span class="z-menuitem-text">Profile</span>
</a>
```

and the image shows OK.

but my ZUL

```
<menuitem label="Delete" image="/img/navigation/delete.png"/>
```

generates this HTML

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="b2IQyj3-a" class="z-menuitem-cnt">
 <span class="z-menuitem-img" style="background-image:url(/main/img/navigation/delete.png)"></span> 
 Delete
</a>
```

they differs a lot i am Using ZK. EE 6.5.2 what i am doing wrong..

i also try to do this by hand using Debugger http://sourceforge.net/p/zk1/bugs/2244/ without success.

Tested Browsers

```
Chrome latest version[Versión 32.0.1700.76 m]
Mozilla latest version[26.0]..
```

Environment

```
Apache Tomcat/7.0.41
ZK 6.5.2 EE (build: 2013032614)
Java SE 7  jdk1.7.0_21
Windows Seven 64 bits.
```

Comment: ZK demo is based on ZK 7.0.0 now and ZK 7.0.0 changed the dom structure a lot, this is why they differs a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke I reproduced your problem on Zk fiddle [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/ufj70h/1-Menuitem-image-not-showing)

As you can see it works under zk 7.0.0 but but doesn't work zk 6.5.2 and zk 6.5.3.

I tested myself to under zk 6.5.3.
If I set the google image, I don't get the image in the popup.
But if I make a delete.png image local it works (but it is caption sensitive!).

Very strange...

But for your project, try (if you are allowed) to upgrade to 6.5.3 and test there.

edit : I added to your bugreport this fiddle.

Greetz chill.

Comment: hello Chill this may be consider as a bug?

Comment: I think its a bug yes, that's why I added the fiddle to your bugreport.(Did your code work under 6.5.3?)

Comment: it works as you said.... thanks for everything i will report this error to my manager. thanks a lot and god bless..